# Upsert using CTE in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert, upsert

I need to upsert my pairs table using a with ins statement from python. I am gettin the error: `psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: missing FROM-clause entry for table "ins" LINE 1: ... pairs_dup_key DO UPDATE SET exchange_pair_symbol=ins.exchan...`

This is the sql code that I am running

```
WITH ins (a, b, c) AS
        (VALUES ('sdf',2,3))
        INSERT INTO pairs
        (foo_id,v,w)
        SELECT foo.id, ins.b, ins.c
        FROM
        ins
        LEFT JOIN foo ON foo.name=ins.a
        ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT pairs_key DO UPDATE SET v=ins.b, w=ins.c;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is the closing `)` for `VALUES`?

Comment: The CTE has to be with the `SELECT`, not with the `INSERT`.

Comment: Why are you using a `WITH` statement at all instead of a simple `FROM VALUES`?

Comment: @snakecharmerb sorry fixed the typo

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe sorry, I'm not sure how I need to interpret that advice... could you please elaborate?

Comment: @Bergi my table has a foreign key constraint on foo.id which is why I do the join statement. My understanding is that using cte is the way to go when trying to insert in this case as described here. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46410/how-do-i-insert-a-row-which-contains-a-foreign-key please let me know if there is a better way.

Comment: @sev See the first snippet in the [second answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/46477/188406) to the question you linked. No need for a CTE to do the JOIN.

Comment: @sev would it be what you're looking for? `INSERT INTO pairs (foo_id,v,w) 
SELECT foo.id, ins.b, ins.c 
FROM (VALUES ('sdf',2,3)) ins (a,b,c)
LEFT JOIN foo ON foo.name=ins.a
ON CONFLICT (foo_id) DO UPDATE SET v=EXCLUDED.v, w=EXCLUDED.w;` ?

Comment: @Bergi thanks a lot, seems I dont really need the CTE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the `EXCLUDED` variable in your upsert.

Keep in mind that, after the conflict, the values of `ins.a` and `ins.b` no longer point to their origin, but to the first attempt to insert them into table `pairs` in the columns `v` and `w`. So, if you want to access these values, you must look into `EXCLUDED`, not to go back to the columns from the previous `SELECT` statement. Also, you do not need a `CTE` for that. A simple `FROM (VALUES...)` would suffice, e.g.

```
INSERT INTO pairs (foo_id,v,w) 
SELECT foo.id, ins.b, ins.c 
FROM (VALUES ('sdf',2,3)) ins (a,b,c)
LEFT JOIN foo ON foo.name=ins.a
ON CONFLICT (foo_id) DO UPDATE SET v=EXCLUDED.v, w=EXCLUDED.w;
```

However, if you must stick to the CTE try this..

```
WITH ins (a, b, c) AS
  (VALUES ('sdf',2,3)
)
INSERT INTO pairs (foo_id,v,w) 
SELECT foo.id, ins.b, ins.c 
FROM ins LEFT JOIN foo ON foo.name=ins.a
ON CONFLICT (foo_id) DO UPDATE SET v=EXCLUDED.v, w=EXCLUDED.w;
```

Comment: This works! Do I understand correctly that EXCLUDED is a reference to the row which was not inserted because of the conflict?

Comment: Also it seems i do not need the CTE